# Volatility of EUR/USD: is this correct?

Tags: volatility, returns, fx, analysis, technical-analysis

Let `x` be the `closeBid` price of EUR/USD, sampled every 5 minutes during year 2015 (historical data). This is the variation (is it correct to call it *5-minutes returns*?) for each 5-minutes period:

```
r = x[1:] / x[:-1] - 1
```

What's the formula to have the (moving) **volatility** over 1 year?

I tried this way:

```
rolling_stddev(r, 288*10)     # 10 days, since 288 periods of 5 minutes in 1 day
```

The results is:

[image]

**Is it a correct measure of volatility?** (i.e. standard deviation of the returns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I thought about voting to close this question as it deals with Matlab synthax a lot.
I ignore the Matlab stuff.

You have 5-minutes data. So an estmator of volatility over any sample of size $N$ (e.g. 100) will be an estimator of the vol of your 5-min returns. Usually volatility is quotes as "per annum" or "pa". This means that using the square root of time rule you can multiply your estimate by the number of 5-minute intervals in a year. Thus if you want to quote vola pa then
$$
T = 12*24*260 = 288*260
$$
assuming 260 banking days and you multiply your estimate by $\sqrt{T}$.
If you do the calculation for 10 days then $T=288*10$.

The $T$, the holding period, is independent from the number of returns that you use in order to estimate the 5-minutes vol.

Doing the things rolling does not change anything of the things above. You just push a window forward by 1 return each time.

Comment: This assumes sampling for the entire day (12 * 24). Would that be more accurate to do it just for the trading hours?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use an exponentially weighted moving average.

There's a nice tutorial video by the Bionic Turtle [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P_tr9_Ue220)

Comment: Ok for EMA, right. But more generally, is it mostly correct (to use standard deviation of returns) ? Would you multiply by some constant?